# Setting year in date picker according to current year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to limit the starting year of datepicker to 70 years back of current year and end year to 18 years back of current year. The code I tried is as shown below:

```
$(function() {
    var endyear=new Date().getFullYear()-18;
    var startyear=new Date().getFullYear()-70;
    $('#dob').datepick({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: endyear:startyear
    });
});
```

But this is not working. How can I set the start and end date as calculated, in jquery datapicker.

Also I want to start the month from the current month and all past dates of current day in the datepicker should be disabled. ie, if current date in datepicker is 05/02/1996, then the dates 01 to 04 should be disabled. I am doing this for restricting users from selecting a date which is invalid for age (ie for those who selects a dob 18years below). How can I achieve this?

Comment: First of all ... what datepicker do you use? There are tons of datepickers and variants out there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Year range needs to be a string, also you will have to set the max and min dates

```
$(function () {
    var start = new Date();
    start.setFullYear(start.getFullYear() - 70);
    var end = new Date();
    end.setFullYear(end.getFullYear() - 18);

    $('#dob').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: start,
        maxDate: end,
        yearRange: start.getFullYear() + ':' + end.getFullYear()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Js3S6/)